# Play Google Music from Android app to PC

Tags: google-chrome, audio, android, chromecast

I like the way that you can turn your PC to youtube tv/player by going to https://www.youtube.com/tv#/browse and pair it with an Android phone. Then, android app can play videos in this Chrome tab.

I want to do the same with my music stored in Google Music (music.google.com). I want to control the playlist from my phone and but I want the PC with speakers to play the actual sound. See the youtube.com/tv - you can search and select the clip on the phone, but it will play in the PC browser remotely.

Is it possible to do this? Some site or some Chrome extension?

Comment: I'm sorry, I really don't understand this question as much as I try to read it. Could you rephrase your question a little?

Comment: @Jiri Going on similar lines to Rik's AirDroid, http://www.snappea.com/ allows you to sign in with Google to connect to your phone

Comment: @Robula I want to control a playlist from the phone, but I want the PC (with speakers) to play the music. See the Youtube.com/tv - you can search and select the clip on the phone, but it will play in the PC browser remotely. I will try to clarify the question.

Comment: Okay. So you're using the YouTube Remote app from Google to control youtube/tv on your PC remotely from your phone. You are looking for a similar technology to select songs from your Google Play Music collection using your Android device and then play them remotely on your PC? Am I right?

Comment: @Robula Yes, thats what I looking for.

Comment: Okay. Check my answer. :)

Answer (score 4):

Does your computer have Bluetooth? If so, you can pair it with Android and all sound can go through your PC speakers. You'll need to use your phone to control the player, though.

[image]
[image]

Upside is you can use **any** app on your phone and the sound will go through your PC-speakers.

---

Another option (using WiFi) is something like [AirDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.sand.airdroid). After installing you can connect via the browser [web.airdroid.com](http://web.airdroid.com/) and play your music. It's not exactly the Google Music-app but it will work. If your phone it out of reach (to control the playback) you'll want to use this option.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the blootooth solution is nice, but I don't have a bluetooth dongle ready to test it now. I will definitely try that later. I was more interested in solution that sends just playlist to the PC/browser the similar way the youtube.com/tv works. Airdroid is not what I am looking for.

Comment: How do you access the window on the first screen? What exact steps? I don't have it on Windows 10

Comment: @Suncatcher It seems like Microsoft has disabled A2DP sink capabilities since Window 8 (It's what gave Windows the ability to act as bluetooth speaker to phones). There seems to be some commercial bluetooth driver which are capable of this but they cost money. See [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1199132/is-there-any-way-to-make-windows-10-act-as-a-a2dp-sink) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29452016/bluetooth-a2dp-sink-in-windows-8-1). Maybe with the term `a2dp sink` you can find more yourself.

Answer (score 1):

Okay. Using your Android device you wish to select songs from your Google Play Music collection and then have them played remotely on your PC.

I have a suggestion, though I have not tried this myself. I use a Media Player at home called MusicBee, it holds my entire music collection and I am able to control this media player remotely from an Android app

- **MusicBee:** http://getmusicbee.com/
- **MusicBee Google Play Music Plugin:** http://musicbee.wikia.com/wiki/Google_Play_Music_Access
- **MusicBee Remote for Android:** https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kelsos.mbrc&hl=en_GB

Now I'm not sure how the MusicBee Google Play Music plugin will behave with the remote control app, but I'm guessing it will act like an additional playlist. I will try this at home myself later on.

**EDIT:** I found a few Chrome extensions!

**Remote4Play**

Android App: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.wiltongarcia.remote4play

Chrome Ext: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/remote4play/lkjonomhhimombmgjmabiakpcafllnge